# Crear contenedor en css

Tags: html, css

Como se podría crear un contenedor solo desde css sin modificar ni agregar nada en el html?

Por ejemplo, en el html tengo lo siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Encabezado</h1>
        <h2>2do encabezado</h2>
        <p>1er párrafo</p>
        <p>2do párrafo</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Como se podría hacer en CSS para crear un contenedor por ejemplo tomando nada mas desde h2(2do encabezado) hasta el ultimo p(2do párrafo). Y a su vez darle los estilos a ese contenedor como yo quiera. SIN TOCAR EL HTML ni javascrip ni nada, solo CSS.

Comment: Un forma podria ser   padding: 70px;

Comment: la respuesta a la pregunta del titulo es que no se puede, ya que desde css no vas a poder crear elementos html. Como te respondieron abajo, usando el body como contenedor y usando nth para asegurarte que luego puedas agregar mas h2 o p al html sin que se vean afectados, es la mejor forma de simularlo.

Comment: Hola, Luis. Lamentablemente, no se puede.

Answer (score 0):

Bunas Luis, todo depende del tipo de estilo CSS que le quieras dar a lo que tienes allí, sin embargo para darle un estilo a los 3 juntos podrías hacer algo así

```
h2 , p {
  /*  tu estilo aqui  */
}
```

sin embargo al ser el elemento padre el body, eso afectaría irremediablemente a todos los elementos h2 y p que hayan en tu código

en el caso exacto de de tu código seria además

```
body p:first-child {
  /* primer elemento <p> del body */
}

body p:last-child {
  /* ultimo elemento <p> del body */
}
```

Comment: Hola Nelson, entiendo tu comentario, pero ahí le estaría dando estilos solos a los elementos h2 y p. Y no es eso lo que quiero, quiero crear un contenedor desde css en cual pueda separar desde el h2 hasta el ultimo p. Y así separar todo ese contenido del h1. Claro en el hmtl podría colocar un div o cualquier otra etiqueta que los meta en un contenedor que es muy fácil. Pero la idea es no tocar en lo absoluto el html.